# Expected time until random walk with positive drift crosses a positive boundary

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk, stopping-times

Let $x_1,x_2,...$ be i.i.d real-valued random variables with $\mathbb{E}[x_i] > 0$. Let $S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ be the partial sums of the r.v.s let and $N= \inf\{ n \mid S_n > h\}$ be the first time the sum crosses the positive threshold $h$. My question has two related parts.

1. I can show that if the $x_i$ has bounded variance then $P(N < \infty)  = 1$. However, it is intuitive to me that this should be true even if the second moment of the random variable does not exist. So how can I prove that $P(N< \infty)$ just assuming $\mathbb{E}[|x_i|] < \infty$? (of course still assuming positive drift)
2. I have seen it used in many papers that $\mathbb{E}[N] < \infty$. However,  I can find no proof of this in any books that I looked at. I have seen proofs that make the additional assumption of a lower barrier, but they do not apply in my case (technically my lower barrier is $-\infty$). How to prove that the expected time is finite?

Comment: 1. Law of large numbers. 2. LLN can be used too (a bit trickier).

Comment: @zhoraster That's interesting, care to expand on how LLN can be used for #2? One is to show $P(S_n > h)$ decays sufficiently quickly, such as $O(1/n^{2})$, but I don't know how to go about that.

Comment: Loosely, let $$\tau_k = \inf\{n\ge \tau_{k-1}: S_n - S_{\tau_{k-1}} > h\}. $$ Then $\tau_k$ is a random walk with positive jumps. If the jumps had infinite expectation, then $\tau_n/n\to \infty$, $n\to \infty$. But this would contradict LLN for $S_n$ (as they would grow sublinearly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the strong law of large numbers $S_n\to \infty$ a.s. Thus, $\mathsf{P}(N<\infty)=1$ (for $h>0$). As for the expectation, for any $r\ge 1$, $\mathsf{E}N^r<\infty$ iff $\mathsf{E}|x_1^{-}|^r<\infty$ (see [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176996709) for details).